# ScreenManager kivy&python

Tags: python, kivy

У меня есть меню, в нём есть кнопка "играть". Нажав на кнопку пользователя перебрасывает на другой экран с игрой, и в экране с игрой, есть кнопка "Выйти в меню". Проблема в том что если пользователь нажмет на "Играть", а потом на "Выйти в меню", То он попадет в меню но функции в игре так и будут работать.
main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window

import random

Window.size = (320,640)
class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass
class Menu(Screen):
    pass
class Game(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.printing, 2)

    def printing(self, *args):
        print('TEST')
class Main(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main().run()
```

Main.kv

```
Manager:
    Menu:
        name:'menu'
    Game:
        name:'game'

<Menu>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: '50dp'
            spacing: '20dp'
            
            Button:
                text: 'Игра'
                on_release:
                    app.root.transition.direction = 'down'
                    app.root.current = 'game'
<Game>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'


        Button:
            text: 'Выйти в меню'
            on_release:
                app.root.transition.direction = 'down'
                app.root.current = 'menu'
```

не знаю как сделать так чтобы при нажатие кнопки "выйти в меню" - игра останавливалась.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Menu(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        if self.manager.has_screen('game'):
            Clock.unschedule(self.manager.get_screen('game').printing)
```